# How can I configure my app with Google services on Google Developers Console again?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-sdk

[There is no button to enable/disable service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi85t.jpg)

Hi, I want to change tracking id of Google Analytics for my app.

In [enable Google services for your app](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) page, I got a configuration for my app with test tracking id. After testing, I try to change my configuration with real tracking id which I want to track, however, I cannot find any disable or edit button to change configuration for Google services.

I changed google-services.json manually, but it doesn't work properly. How can I configure my app with google services again? Thank you.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to go through the configuration again and get a new json file? If you're using different project or account and not going through the config, you can check that things are enabled manually in the developer console as well. You can also check if you're using the correct tracking ids in your analytics console.